# When using this .js 2 times on a single page it only works in the one instance

Tags: javascript

This script creates menu tabs above a text area. The script works if use only once on a page, I however need to use it twice on a single page, to create 2 text areas, each with a menu above them. As soon as I use it twice only one instance works. Any suggestions.

```
window.onload=function() {

  // get tab container
  var container = document.getElementById("tabContainer");
    // set current tab
    var navitem = container.querySelector(".tabs ul li");
    //store which tab we are on
    var ident = navitem.id.split("_")[1];
    navitem.parentNode.setAttribute("data-current",ident);
    //set current tab with class of activetabheader
    navitem.setAttribute("class","tabActiveHeader");

    //hide two tab contents we don't need
    var pages = container.querySelectorAll(".tabpage");
    for (var i = 1; i < pages.length; i++) {
      pages[i].style.display="none";
    }

    //this adds click event to tabs
    var tabs = container.querySelectorAll(".tabs ul li");
    for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
      tabs[i].onclick=displayPage;
    }
}

// on click of one of tabs
function displayPage() {
  var current = this.parentNode.getAttribute("data-current");
  //remove class of activetabheader and hide old contents
  document.getElementById("tabHeader_" + current).removeAttribute("class");
  document.getElementById("tabpage_" + current).style.display="none";

  var ident = this.id.split("_")[1];
  //add class of activetabheader to new active tab and show contents
  this.setAttribute("class","tabActiveHeader");
  document.getElementById("tabpage_" + ident).style.display="block";
  this.parentNode.setAttribute("data-current",ident);
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do? The `onload` handler will obviously only run once, when the body is loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Havn't found solution yet, but FYI, you originally marked this as jQuery, if it had been jquery, you could easily break a few lines of that code and write it as simple as: (depending on version)

```
function displayPage(e) {
    var current = $(this).parent().attr("data-current");
    $("#tabHeader_" + current).removeClass("tabActiveHeader")
    $("#tabpage_" + current).hide();

    var ident = this.id.split("_")[1];
    $(this).addClass("tabActiveHeader");
    $("#tabpage_" + ident).show();
    $(this).parent().attr({ 'data-current': ident })
}
$(function() {
    var container = $("#tabContainer"),
        navitem = container.find((".tabs ul li")).first(),
        ident = navitem[0].id.split("_")[1];
    navitem.addClass("tabActiveHeader").parent().attr({ 'data-current': ident });

    $(".tabpage").filter(function(i) { return i>0; }).hide();
    // OR
    // $(".tabpage:not(:first-child)").hide();

    $(".tabs ul li").on("click", displayPage)
});​
```

### See WORKING Example of the previous jQUERY in this jsFiddle

ALSO, Have you look at [jQueryUI.Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/)?

Comment: Thanks. excellent suggestion, jqueryUi.Tabs was the easier more efficient option

Comment: Glad I could help, but keep in mind, your JS looks very strong, but if you're using jQuery (and now jQueryUI) dont forget the "strength" those libs provide and they really do help you to "do more, write less".  I suggest using the latest version at all times as much as MS suggest the latest .net to any c# coder.  They realy are (and i've reviewed them all) some of the best and most powerful js libs online.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hard-setting `window.onload`—which replaces the last-set handler with the new one—use the following code that registers an arbitrary number of event handlers for the same event on the same object:

```
window.addEventListener('load',function(){
  // Your code here
},false);
```

[More can be read about element.addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) and specifically [IE Support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener#Legacy_Internet_Explorer_and_attachEvent)

*This will not work for older versions of IE; if you need this support, I strongly recommend using a cross-browser library like jQuery. You originally tagged your question as relating to jQuery, but there is no jQuery used in your code.*

Comment: Support for IE event registration is only like 6 lines (assuming nothing older than IE7). I would recommend not including this library (jQuery) for the sole purpose of Event handling. There are many more lightweight alternatives.

Comment: He originally posted tagged as jQuery, perhaps he's already including jQuery lib, but simply doesn't realize what power he has added